# Why does Numpy seem to be slow even after vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy

I implemented a Polynomial class in Numpy as part of an exercise. I also created another class using standard Python lists & loops which I have added below.

```
class Polynomial: # Implemented with Numpy
  '''
  This class is implementing a polynomial.

  Instance variable --> coefficients which contains the coeff of the polynomial.

  Methods:
  __init__ initializes the class.
  __call__ returns value of the polynomial given value of x
  derivative takes derivative of the polynomial and returns the new coefficients.
  '''
  def __init__(self, coefficients):
    self.coefficients = coefficients

  def __call__(self, x):
    polynomial_value = 0
    X = np.ones(len(self.coefficients))
    X[1:] = x
    return np.cumprod(X) @ self.coefficients

  def derivative(self):
    n = len(self.coefficients)
    new_coeff = self.coefficients[1:] * np.cumsum(np.ones(n-1))
    self.coefficients = new_coeff
    return self.coefficients
```

```
class Polynomial: # Implemented without Numpy
  def __init__(self, coefficients):
    self.coefficients = coefficients

  def __call__(self, x):
    polynomial_value = 0
    for i in range(len(self.coefficients)):
      polynomial_value += self.coefficients[i]*(x**i)
    return polynomial_value

  def derivative(self):
    n = len(self.coefficients)
    new_coeff=[]
    for i in range(1,n):                  # Note we are dropping a0 and thus we
      new_coeff.append(self.coefficients[i]*i)  # are starting from 1
    self.coefficients = new_coeff
    return self.coefficients
```

I tested the 2 codes using the following routines:

1. Numpy

```
%%timeit
import random
#Runtime on polynomial class
N = 10000
for i in range(1,N):
  coeff = np.random.randint(0, 100, size = 10)
  my_poly = Polynomial(coeff)
  x = random.randint(0,100)
  my_poly(x)
```

2. Standard Python lists & for loops

```
%%timeit
import random
#Runtime on polynomial class
N = 10000
for i in range(1,N):
  coeff = random.sample(range(0, 100), 10)
  my_poly = Polynomial(coeff)
  x = random.randint(0,100)
  my_poly(x)
```

The time for 1st implementation (Numpy) was 249 ms and the time for the 2nd one was 153 ms.

Why is this the case? Have I implemented vectorization incorrectly either in defining the class or testing it? Or is there something else happening?

Comment: I suspect this is mostly due to your working with tiny data. `numpy` has significant overhead, which is OK when working with large arrays. Try to compare with, say, `coeff = random.sample(range(0, 100), 1000)`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! That was really helpful. It motivated me to try to understand how Numpy works under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you're doing this for small equations with only 10 coefficients. I ran your code for 100 coefficients (i.e a 99-degree equation) and the numpy one took 250 ms while the Python list one took 8.23 seconds. Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would like to upvote and accept, but don't have enough reputation right now.

Comment: @Manish You can always accept answers on your own question.